# Cursor change in Runtime

Tags: cursor, runtime

I am new to C# and WPF. I need to change the mouse cursor to a Rectangular type cursor in runtime.

The cursor should show when the custom cursor should show when mouse move out of the window. and it should change to mouse cursor when mouse moves into the window.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? It is way easier for us to help you make it work than tell you what to do out of the blue.

Comment: I made a user control and tried to load it with xmlreader. When mouse goes out of the application's window, i tried to assign the loaded user control to this.cursor. But i couldn't meet the requirement.